# How do I use the ascii function in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I am attempting to learn how to use the `ascii` function in Python 3.

The documentation reads

> **ascii(object)**
>
> As repr(), return a string containing a printable representation of an
>   object, but escape the non-ASCII characters in the string returned by
>   repr() using \x, \u or \U escapes. This generates a string similar to
>   that returned by repr() in Python 2.

However, when I attempt to use `print ascii("c")` I receive the error:

```
print ascii("c")
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I use this function?

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print`  is a function in python3, you're getting that error because you're trying to use it as a statement.

```
print (ascii("c"))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> print (ascii("c"))
'c'
>>> print ascii("c")
  File "<ipython-input-3-c44db7d0eada>", line 1
    print ascii("c")
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Thanks!